# Lazy Module returns blank page

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I'm running `Angular CLI 6.0.2` and trying to use `Lazy Module` load for some components.

I've followed documentation and configured my `app.module` as below:

```
    const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path      : '',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
    {
        path      : 'main',
        component: FuseMainComponent,
      canActivate: [AuthguardService]
    },
  {
    path      : 'appqos',
    component: AppqosComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthguardService]
  },
  {
    path      : 'tasks',
    // component: TaskviewerComponent,
    // canActivate: [AuthguardService]
    loadChildren: './taskviewer/taskviewer.module#TaskviewerModule'

imports: [
...,
 RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
]
```

The `lazy module` to load is set as below:

```
 const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tasks',
    component: TaskviewerComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    NgxDatatableModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)

  ],
  declarations: [TaskviewerComponent],
  exports: [
    TaskviewerComponent, RouterModule
  ]

})
export class TaskviewerModule { }
```

When I browse to the 'tasks' route, the components is showing as blank page. I don't see any error in the console. In the network tab it's just showing it's loading file `taskviewer-taskviewer-module-ngfactory.js` instead of the `chunk.js`

I tried different tutorials and official documentation as well as using `ng serve --aot` but it yields the same result.

Is there any way to see why the component is not properly rendered and returning a blank page ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the url for TaskviewerComponent is `localhost:4200/tasks/tasks`.
if you want something like `localhost:4200/tasks`
in child route define:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', // <-- no name path here
    component: TaskviewerComponent
  }
];
```

look at https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading-route-configuration in **app-routing.module.ts** and **crisis-center-routing.module.ts** for how to have a default route for lazy loaded modules.

Comment: After an year, lot of same questions but this answer solved - Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, actually my lazy module needs to have path: ''

I should have checked more thoroughly.